# Is there a ODATA query to linq where expression (ODATA to Linq )

Tags: linq, odata

Basically,

I would like to convert odata query expression **"$filter", "itemID eq 1"**  to **where(w=>w.itemID==1)**

Is there a ready library for this operation? Otherwise I need to code it by using DynamicLinq classes and linqKit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using Microsoft WebAPI with the following NuGet packages installed:

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/

http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata

Which lets me write things like:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;

// Some stuff left out

[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Item> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Item> query)
{        
    var items = query.ApplyTo(from item in context.Items select item);
    return (IQueryable<Item>) items;
}
```

Then I can call it using jQuery Ajax (for the sake of the example, I prefer to use BackboneJS) like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/api/items', data: $.param({ '$filter': 'ID eq 1' }) });
```

Which will then return only the items with an ID equal to 1, which I think is what you are after?

If itemID is the main ID of the object you are retrieving, I would probably follow REST principles and create and API where the url to retrieve an item with the ID of 1 would be:

```
/api/items/1
```

And only use oData queries on the collection of items if I was querying based on other properties of the items in the collection, or do something like below for example when retrieving the top 10 records.

```
$.ajax({ url: '/api/items', data: $.param({ '$top': 10 }) });
```

Comment: query.ApplyTo seems what I'm looking.I need it on mono. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use following NuGet package to apply filter:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.OData.Linq

Code sample would be:

```
using System.Linq;
using Community.OData.Linq;

// dataSet in this example - any IQuerable<T> 
Sample[] filterResult = dataSet.OData().Filter("Id eq 2 or Name eq 'name3'").ToArray();
```

Currently supported: filter and orderby in v4 format

Answer (score 0):

You Can use  [Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.azure.odata?view=azure-dotnet)

string filter = new ODataQuery(x => x.itemID == 1).Filter;

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. 1 year later it'll be a decade after the question. I'm happy to see some improvement in .net libs, even I moved to java back meantime :)