# Is there any ODATA query to QueryDSL predicate expression

Tags: java, odata, querydsl

Basically,

I would like to convert ODATA query expression "$filter", "itemID eq 1" to QueryDsl `Predicate`.

Currently, We're using an optional predicate in our APIs and able to pass property filtering as
`baseApiUrl/?xprop=1&yprop=abc`, with this we can filter `xprop` and `yprop` for a single logical operator **dynamically**. However, ODATA provide dynamic filtering, and we would like to utilize that option if there's any in order to apply different logical operators for per field.

Especially $filter part mentioned in the [rfc here](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc31358948), would be a great help.

`BooleanExpression filterExp= QItems.items.itemId.eq(1);`

Is there any ready library or community project for this operation?

*Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154469/is-there-a-odata-query-to-linq-where-expression-odata-to-linq), but it was for .net*